# Best PowerShell verb for Logging something?

Tags: powershell, shell-verbs

In a PowerShell script I have a function like `Log-Statistics()` which just outputs some stuff to stdout. But it might as well output stuff to a specific log file.

However, `Log-` is not an [approved PS verb](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/developer/cmdlet/approved-verbs-for-windows-powershell-commands?view=powershell-7).

Any recommends ?

I'm considering:

- `Out-Statistics()`
- `Write-Statistics()`
- `LogStatistics()`

Comment: How is `Out-Log()`/`ol()`? You're question is a bit unclear, can you clarify what you want? Sounds like `Out-File` will do the same thing...

Comment: Per the PowerShell approved verbs  Write- would be appropriate. If you are updating an existing log Update-. If you are overwriting the log Set- would be used.  Pretty much your choice.

Comment: the idea that i have most often seen is `Write-SpiffyThing` or some variant of that. [*grin*]

Answer (score 2):

Considering other examples, I have decided to go with `WRITE` as it does do actions to write (either on screen or as file).
`OUT` (for me) implies that this is output (i.E. end of pipeline)

I have `Write-Log` and `Write-ErrorLog` as helper functions (and other variations thereof) that I use (though not best practice, I generally fit my Write-Log with an `-Append` switch as to not overwrite a log (and to find all instances where I do write output quickly). Ideally that is done with the already existing `Add-Content`).

It also fits neatly into their cousins, `Write-Error`, `Write-Warning`, `Write-Verbose`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/developer/cmdlet/approved-verbs-for-windows-powershell-commands) you link to unfortunately doesn't reflect the fact that what `Out-*` cmdlets have in common is to use PowerShell's [*for-display output formatting system*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/developer/format/formatting-file-overview) (resulting in rich, multi-line representations of objects).

Given that logs are usually *line-oriented* and should ideally be suited to *programmatic processing*, `Out` is therefore *not* the right verb<sup>[1]</sup> to use.

---

Note that PowerShell commands do not write their (regular) output to *stdout* (standard output) as such, given that PowerShell has a more sophisticated system of *6* output streams - see [about_Redirections](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Redirection?) - where stream number `1`, the success output stream, is meant for *data only*.

---

`Add`, following the example of `Add-Content`, *appends* to an existing resource while *creating it on demand*.

However, this logic isn't consistent among built-in cmdlets, as some have only a create-or-replace-by-default form (e.g., `Out-File`), with an optional `-Append` switch as an *opt-in* to *appending* content.

---

Based on the above, one option is:

- Use `Add-Statistics` and, by default, have it output to the *information stream* (`6`), via
  [`Write-Information`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility/Write-Information) (assuming the command is implemented in PowerShell), so it doesn't interfere with *data* (success-stream) output.

  - Note: `Write-Information` is *silent* by default, which you can change via the `-InformationAction` common parameter or the `$InformationPreference` preference variable. Alternatively, use [`Write-Host`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility/Write-Host), which (in PSv5+) also writes to the information stream (`6`), but its output *does* display by default.
- Either add an `-OutFile` parameter to `Add-Statistics` to write to a file instead (creating it on demand), or let the *caller* redirect the information-stream output to a file with something like `6>log.txt` (which works even when `Write-Information` output would be silent, if not redirected).

---

<sup>[1] As stated in the linked documentation, "verb" is used loosely here; some of PowerShell's approved verbs aren't verbs in a strict natural-language grammar sense.</sup>

Comment: Would you recommend using `Add` for code that inserts records to a database?

Comment: @lit, that's probably the best choice, yes. `Write` may work too, but it has a connotation of writing to _streams_.

Answer (score 0):

I would use something like Invoke-LogStatistics()

Comment: I would not use `Invoke`. Invoke is a `Lifecycle` verb that "Performs an action, such as running a command or a method." In this case, no new execution is started.